# Sharepoint: PowerPivot Chart not show + Menu bar not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powerpivot

Just uploaded a PowerPivot Workbook to a PowerPivot Gallery on Sharepoint 2013 site. I opened it but only the slicers are shown, not the Pivot chart.

At the position of the pivot chart, there is only an [x] icon.

Apart from that, I don't see any notice, error information or similar.

I'm the admin of both SharePoint farm and SQL Server.

I googled but did not find anything, not sure what I missed.

Edit 1: Menu bar also deos not work, nothing happens on click. I think there is something wrong with my Excel application on SharePoint.

Comment: What does you ULS log says when trying to access the chart? Are your excel services up and running? Are the chart in a trusted excel location? Can you open other excel documents?

Comment: i dont know how to look for error in ULS logs, i mean i know where it is, just dont know where to look in the file. Did try upload a simple excel work book to the gallery, same happen, menu bar not work, cannot event click on the cell. On the powerpivot workbook, when i click the slicer, the chart show up and fucntion normally.

Comment: This is one of the exception i found when look thorugh log file: Result=Id=ImageGenFailed; Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ImageException: Failed to generate a chart or image for http://sp13/PowerPivot%20Gallery/Book1.xlsx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

1. Chart not show : Change value of **Maximum Chart or Image Size** in Trusted File Location of Excel Service Application ( i changed it to 100)
2. Share Point Excel Menu Bar not work : use FireFox + IETab addon